# Cannot find data type boolean

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

While creating a table, I get following error message.

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 1 Column, parameter, or variable #4:
>   Cannot find data type boolean.

When trying to use this script:

```
create table artists ( artist_id    int, 
                       artist_name  varchar(60), 
                       artist_dob   datetime, 
                       poster_in_stock  boolean )
```

Any suggestion to what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Without seeing your `create` statement, it's all guesswork, but I'm guessing you're using `boolean` instead of `bit`

Comment: Boss  in SQL server boolean is not exist as datatype You  should use bit datatype for that purpose.

Comment: create table artists
( artist_id   int,
  artist_name  varchar(60), 
  artist_dob  datetime,
  poster_in_stock boolean
)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your create statment to:

```
create table artists ( artist_id    int, 
                       artist_name  varchar(60), 
                       artist_dob   datetime, 
                       poster_in_stock  bit )
```

There is no such type `boolean` in SQL, you need to use `bit`.

### [MSDN bit (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx)

> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.
>   The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
>   is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.